# Transitions between two Android activities not behaving as expected

Tags: android, transition, android-transitions

I have some transitions set up between two activities, `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`, but they don't behave as expected. The Android API is 22 (5.0 Lollipop). A slow transition between activities is used because both activities have webviews that take a few seconds for their layouts to stabilize.

`ActivityA` is a `NativeActivity` and has two methods for switching between activities that are invoked from C++ code.

```
class ActivityA extends NativeActivity
{
    ...
    protected void startActivityA()
    {
        startActivity(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
        overridePendingTransitions(R.anim.slow_fade_in, R.anim.slow_fade_out);
    }

    protected void startActivityB()
    {
        startActivity(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
        overridePendingTransitions(R.anim.slow_fade_in, R.anim.slow_fade_out);
    }
    ...
}
```

`ActivityB` is an `Activity`.

The `res/anim/show_fade_in.xml` transition is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:factor="1.0"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillBefore="true" android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

The `res/anim/slow_fade_out.xml` transition is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:factor="1.0"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillBefore="true" android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

When `ActivityA.startActivityB()` is invoked from C++ code, I notice two things happen:

1. A slow fade to light gray of `ActivityA`.
2. The sudden appearance of the stabilized `ActivityB` webview.

I don't understand why #2 is a sudden appearance and not a slow fade.

When `ActivityA.startActivityA()` is invoked from C++ code, all I see is a quick cross-fade from `ActivityB` to `ActivityA`. I don't understand why I get a quick cross-fade instead of the programmed slow fades.

Why might I not be getting the results I expect?